# MongoDB Aggregation Lookup with AddFields and NOR

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a $lookup operation that fails when I try to use $nor in the pipeline with addFields.

It fails saying: ""errmsg" : "Invalid addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression 'nor'".

What am I doing wrong?

Can I use any expression inside AddFields?

cheers

Example:

```
    {
        from : "Partner",
        localField : "PartnerId",
        foreignField : "_id",
        as : "PartnerInfo",
        pipeline : [
            {
                $project : {
                    _id : 0,
                    "Company.DiversityCollaborators" : 1,
                    "Company.DiversityLeadership" : 1,
                    "Company.DiversityShareHolders" : 1
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields : {
                    "HasDiversity" : {
                        $cond : [
                            {
                                $or : [
                                    {
                                        $nor : [
                                            {
                                                "$Company.DiversityCollaborators" : {
                                                    $size : 0
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $nor : [
                                            {
                                                "$Company.DiversityLeadership" : {
                                                    $size : 0
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $nor : [
                                            {
                                                "$Company.DiversityShareHolders" : {
                                                    $size : 0
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                ]
                            },
                            "Y",
                            "N"
                        ]
                    },
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, the correct expression is $anyElementTrue

cheers

```
"HasDiversity": {
                     $cond:[ { $or: [
                                         { $anyElementTrue: [ "$Company.DiversityCollaborators" ] },
                                         { $anyElementTrue: [ "$Company.DiversityLeadership" ] },
                                         { $anyElementTrue: [ "$Company.DiversityShareHolders" ] },
                         ]} , "S", "N"]  
               },
```